# How to display subtitles as default in an MKV file

Tags: subtitles, mkv

I have an MKV file with multiple subtitles.  I would like to mark one set of those subtitles as default, so that it is turned on by default when the video starts playing.  NOTE: I do not want to "burn" this subtitles set into the video (I want to be able to turn these subtitles off at any point in time if I so choose).

Is there an MKV editing tool that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to your query - 1)setting one of the subtitle streams as the default and 2)automatically displaying it during playback.I'm not aware of a method to force a player to display subtitles if that facility has been turned off in its settings.

For the first facility, try mkvpropedit from [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/index.html) to set the default flag for a subtitle stream. See 2nd [example](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html#mkvpropedit.examples).

Comment: Your solution worked wonderfully.  What do you recommend as a GUI for MKVToolNix?

Comment: The [standard installer](http://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVtoolnix) does come with a GUI. It's what I use. [Here](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=163753)'s a GUI for mkvpropedit, but I haven't used it personally.